# Can't load nuget package written with .NET Core

Tags: f#, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard

I have recently attempted to migrate my open source project GeographicLib.FSharp (https://github.com/SpiegelSoft/GeographicLib) to .NET Standard. I can build the project, package it and upload it to nuget, but when I try to load the nuget package into an external .NET Standard Library, I obtain mixed results.

Creating an F# library using `dotnet new classlib -lang f#` and adding the Nuget package via Visual Studio works on the face of it, but I cannot access any of the types I defined in the GeographicLib.FSharp library.

If I create a C# .NET Standard library using the Class Library (.NET Standard) template, then upgrade this package to .NET Standard 1.6, I can add the GeographicLib.FSharp nuget package and access the types as normal.

It appears that importing types from Nuget packages in F# .NET Standard Libraries is broken.

Is there a fix or a workaround for this?

Comment: I hate to say this, but did you restore and re-open the solution / vs after adding the package to the f# library? Not sure if the F# project system can react to deps changes, so you could have a design-time build that doesn't see the new references yet..

Comment: But do consider using `netstandard2.0`.. it creates less problems with the current tooling (conflict resolution)

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio F# extension doesn't yet support .NET Standard or .NET Core projects.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/f-and-net-core-roadmap-update/ for more info and roadmap

If you think is an issue, please open a bug in Visual F# repository https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues

These project build, but doesnt load intellisense in Visual Studio.

Meanwhile you can use other ide/editors, like:

- Visual Studio Code with Ionide extension
- JetBrains Rider
- vim
- emacs
- Visual Studio for Mac